# C# - Adding a RowDefinition to a Grid programmatically using Dispatcher inside a Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, dispatcher

I'm trying to do what is said in the title of the question. I've looked on MSDN that if you used a thread to access the UI thread you need to use the Dispatch call. Anyways that hasn't solved my problem.
This is my code, what do I need to do to solve it? Thanks!:

```
static void example()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < amountRows; i++)
     {
          RowDefinition rowD = new RowDefinition();
          gridSizes.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { gridSizes.RowDefinitions.Add(rowD); }));
          Console.WriteLine("added"); // never gets to here cuz the dispatcher produces an exception
     }
}

Reproduce:
new Thread(() =>
{
    example();
}).Start();
```

This code has been called from the public void of a Window from a WPF project, MainWindow --> Open new Window --> Thread --> Code --> Exception

Comment: you can't update the UI controls from a background thread

Comment: @EhsanSajjad then what I could do, I need to use a thread to gather some data from requests and takes time, not using a thread would pause the UI for few seconds.

Comment: you could use a flag or an event to tell the UI thread when that data is populated, and then bind it or use it in the UI thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Keith Stein said, RowDefinition is a DependencyObject, so in order to call it from a thread Dispatcher.Invoke must be used.

In order to solve the issue I used the next block of code which Invokes the Dispatcher for all the code inside there.

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate ()
{
      //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe because `RowDefinition` is also a `DependencyObject` that you need to create it on the UI thread as well for it to work with your `Grid`. Moving `RowDefinition rowD = new RowDefinition()` into your `Dispatcher.Invoke` call should fix that.

Of course, in the above example that makes the second threat pointless, since it's doing nothing itself, but I'm assuming that in your full code you have the second thread actually doing something.

Comment: True, the example is pointless but on my code, there are important things that I didn't want to disclose, I will try your solution and let you know. Thanks!